# SQL Server synonym that appoint to Database

Tags: sql-server, alias, synonym

I have reviewed documentation and have only seen the possibility of creating synonyms to database objects and aliases for an instance of SQL Server but not a method to create an alias / synonym to a database.
Has anyone found themselves in the same situation and how did they solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for a database alias like for objects with Microsoft SQL Server.

However you can create a linked server to a database even on the same server. This is the closest to get to an alias.

This is actually a pretty nice way to keep code stable while being able to move databases between servers later to scale out.